# How to correctly define numpy dtype

Tags: numpy

I have such piece of code, where I try to load four columns from `csv` file

```
import numpy as np
rtype = np.dtype([('1', np.float), ('2', np.float), ('3', np.float), ('tier', np.str, 32)])
x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.genfromtxt("../Data/out.txt", dtype=rtype, skip_header=1, delimiter=",", usecols=(3, 4, 5, 6), unpack=True)
```

But I have an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

This is a lit bit strange because I have four variables and load four columns.

How to load them correctly? 
IMHO, problem is in `np.dtype` because without it, all works fine (with other types though). I use python3.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `x4` when it loads correctly?  What does `dtype=None` do?

Comment: `unpack=True` doesn't work with `dtype=None`: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4341

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a text like:

```
In [447]: txt=b"""1.2 3.3 2.0 str
     ...: 3.3 3.3 2.2 astring
     ...: """
```

My first choice is `genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` (automatic dtype determination):

```
In [448]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
Out[448]: 
array([(1.2, 3.3, 2.0, b'str'), (3.3, 3.3, 2.2, b'astring')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S7')])
```

Without `dtype` it tries to make everything float - including the string column:

```
In [449]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines())
Out[449]: 
array([[ 1.2,  3.3,  2. ,  nan],
       [ 3.3,  3.3,  2.2,  nan]])
```

I don't use `unpack` much, preferring to get one 2d or structured array. But with unpack:

```
In [450]: x1,x2,x3,x4=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),unpack=True)
In [451]: x1
Out[451]: array([ 1.2,  3.3])
In [452]: x4
Out[452]: array([ nan,  nan])
```

I still get the `nan` for the string column.

Borrowing the dtype from the `dtype=None` case:

```
In [456]: dt=np.dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S7')])
In [457]: dt
Out[457]: dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S7')])
In [458]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),unpack=True,dtype=dt)
Out[458]: 
array([(1.2, 3.3, 2.0, b'str'), (3.3, 3.3, 2.2, b'astring')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S7')])
In [459]: _.shape
Out[459]: (2,)
```

With this compound dtype, `unpack` gives me one item per row of the text, not one item per column.  In other words, `unpack` does not split up the structured fields.

One way to handle the string column and still use unpack is to read the text twice:

first load the float columns:

```
In [462]: x1,x2,x3=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),unpack=True,usecols=[0,1,2])
In [463]: x3
Out[463]: array([ 2. ,  2.2])
```

then load the string column, with `dtype=None` or `S32`:

```
In [466]: x4=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),unpack=True,usecols=[3],dtype=None)
In [467]: x4
Out[467]: 
array([b'str', b'astring'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Another option is to load the structured array, and unpack the fields individually

```
In [468]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
In [469]: data.dtype
Out[469]: dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S7')])
In [470]: x1, x2, x3 = data['f0'],data['f1'],data['f2']
In [471]: x4 = data['f3']
In [472]: x4
Out[472]: 
array([b'str', b'astring'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

The safest way to use `genfromtxt` is

```
data = np.genfromtxt(...)
print(data.shape)
print(data.dtype)
```

and then make sure you understand that shape and dtype before moving on to using the `data` array.